# How can I make an identical matrix with a column vector?

Tags: r

I have a column vector with dimensions 4000x1, and I need to make a matrix with that vector, but the matrix needs to have the column vector as a diagonal and the other numbers as zero. Something like this:

Column Vector

```
> vector <- matrix(c(1:5), ncol=1, nrow=5)
> vector
 [,1]
[1,]    1
[2,]    2
[3,]    3
[4,]    4
```

Matrix

```
   [,1] [,2] [,3]  [,4] 
a    1    0    0    0        
b    0    2    0    0        
c    0    0    3    0
```

How can I produce this output?

Answer (score 3):

This sounds like the `diag()` function, e.g.,

```
> my_vect <- 1:5
> diag(my_vect)
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]
[1,]    1    0    0    0    0
[2,]    0    2    0    0    0
[3,]    0    0    3    0    0
[4,]    0    0    0    4    0
[5,]    0    0    0    0    5
```

By the way, as you have written it `vector` is actually a 5x1 matrix, so you would need to convert it to, well, a vector:

```
> diag(as.vector(vector))
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]
[1,]    1    0    0    0    0
[2,]    0    2    0    0    0
[3,]    0    0    3    0    0
[4,]    0    0    0    4    0
[5,]    0    0    0    0    5
```